# Map numeric input values with text on y-axis in jqplot

Tags: binary, jqplot

I am using jqplot for showing graphs which will show digital as well as binary values. I am using dateAxisRenderer for the x-axis.

The data to be displayed is in the form of [timestamp, value]. Now the analog graph is working properly, but for the binary I have to show ON and OFF instead of 0 and 1 on the y-axis.

I am using ticks for this behavior and converting values to form [0, 'OFF'] , [1, 'ON'] to show the labels on y-axis. The graph shows the labels correctly after this but the values are not shown plotted.

Is there any way to convert the data to display i.e. the 'value' so that the values on y-axis are mapped with the required data to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a second yaxis that is formatted with 'Yes/No' labels:

[image]

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/z5eNz/1/) I used to generate that...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;   

    var line1 = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]];
    var line2 = [[1,1],[2,0],[3,1],[4,1],[5,0]];

    $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2], {
        series: [
            {label: 'Analog'},
            {label: 'Yes/No', 'yaxis':'y2axis'},

        ],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: 'Label'
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: 'Analog'
            },
            y2axis:{
                label: 'Yes/No',           
                ticks: [0,1],
                tickOptions:{formatter: 
                             function (formatString, value){
                                 if (value == 0) return 'No';
                                 else if (value == 1) return 'Yes';
                                 else return "";
                             }}

            }       

        }
    });
});​
```